# How to understand the scope attribute of directive in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, directive

In the guide tutorial of angularjs directive, the directive object could have the scope attribute. It's defining the scope of the directive.

While the scope atribute value could be true, follow is the explanation of the scope:( [link of the scope definition](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object))

> true: A new child scope that prototypically inherits from its parent
>   will be created for the directive's element. **If multiple directives on
>   the same element request a new scope, only one new scope is created.**

I am puzzled by the sentences which was in bold style. How did multiple directives on the same element and they use the same scope?

Answer (score 1):

According to me, this means that the scope would be created per element and not per directive.

Hence the scope would automatically be shared among the directives and not different copies for each directive will be created.

Here in this link https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2729-don-t-blindly-isolate-all-the-scopes-in-angularjs-directives.htm

they have mentioned :

If you're using AngularJS 1.2, the next hurdle is that you cannot apply two isolate-scope directives to the same element. Take a look at the following code. All it does is apply two directives to the same element. And, the directives do nothing but require an isolate-scope.

Hence if you use the same scope variable in both the directives then it will throw the following error

> **Error: error:multidir**
>
> Multiple Directive Resource Contention
>
> Multiple directives [bnThat, bnThis] asking for new/isolated scope on

Hence for such situation, transclusion or place directive in nested manner can do the job.

Example to what I mentioned above is given in the snippet below.

```js
// Create an application module for our demo.
var app = angular.module("Demo", []);
// -------------------------------------------------- //
// -------------------------------------------------- //
// I request an isolate scope directive.
app.directive(
  "bnThis",
  function() {
    // Return the directive configuration. Notice that we are creating an
    // isolate scope, even though we are not binding any expressions.
    return ({
      link: angular.noop,
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {}
    });
  }
);
// -------------------------------------------------- //
// -------------------------------------------------- //
// I request an isolate scope directive.
app.directive(
  "bnThat",
  function() {
    // Return the directive configuration. Notice that we are creating an
    // isolate scope, even though we are not binding any expressions.
    return ({
      link: angular.noop,
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {}
    });
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="Demo">

  <p bn-this bn-that>
    Look at the console output.
  </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

We do not know what the scope will contain at the point where our directive is used.
It is a good practice, therefore, to provide our directive with a well-defined public
facing interface. This ensures that the directive cannot rely on or be affected by
arbitrary properties on the scope where it is used.
We have three options for the scope to be used in our directive and its template. This
is defined in the directive definition:
• To reuse the scope, from the place where the widget is used. This is the
default and corresponds to scope: false.

• To create a child scope, which prototypically inherits from the scope where
the widget is used. You specify this with scope: true.

• To create an isolated scope, which does not prototypically inherit, so that it is
completely isolated from its parent. You specify this by passing an object to
the scope property: scope: { ... }.
We want to completely decouple our widget's template from the rest of the
application, so that there is no danger of data leaking between the two.

**Note:-**[While an isolated scope does not prototypically inherit from its parent,
it can still access its parent's scope through the $parent property.
But this is considered a bad practice because you are undermining the
isolation of the directive from its surroundings.]

Since our scope is now isolated from the parent scope, we need to explicitly map
values between the parent scope and the isolated scope. This is done by referencing
AngularJS expressions on the attributes of the element where the directive appears.
In the case of our pagination directive, the num-pages and current-page attributes
fulfill this role.
We can synchronize the expressions in these attributes with properties on the
template scope through watches. We can set this up manually or we can ask
AngularJS to wire them up for us. There are three types of interface we can specify
between the element's attributes and the isolated scope: interpolate (@), data
bind (=), and expression (&). You specify these interfaces as key-value pairs on
the scope property of the directive definition.
The key is the name of the field on the isolated scope. The value is one of @, =, or &
followed by the name of the attribute on the element:

```
scope: {
 isolated1: '@attribute1',
 isolated2: '=attribute2',
 isolated3: '&attribute3'
}
```

Here we have defined three fields on the isolated scope and AngularJS will map their
values from the specified attributes on the element where the directive appears.

**Note:**[If the attribute name is omitted from the value, then it is assumed that
the attribute has the same name as the isolated scope field:
scope: { isolated1: '@' }
It will expect the attribute to be called isolated1.]

Interpolating the attribute with @
The @ symbol indicates that AngularJS should interpolate the value of the specified
attribute and update the isolated scope property when it changes. Interpolation is
used with {{}} curly braces to generate a string using values from the parent scope.
**Note:-**[A common mistake is to expect an interpolated object to be the object
itself. Interpolation always returns a string. So if you have an object, say
user has a field called userName, then the interpolation of {{user}}
will convert the user object to a string and you will not be able to
access the userName property on the string.]

This attribute interpolation is equivalent to manually $observe the attribute:

```
attrs.$observe('attribute1', function(value) {
 isolatedScope.isolated1 = value;
});
```

attrs.$$observers['attribute1'].$$scope = parentScope;
Binding data to the attribute with =
The = symbol indicates that AngularJS should keep the expression in the specified
attribute and the value on the isolated scope in sync with each other. This is a two-way
data binding that allows objects and values to be mapped directly between the inside
and outside of the widget.
Since this interface supports two way data binding, the expression given
in the attribute should be assignable (that is, refers to a field on the
scope or an object) and not an arbitrary computed expression.
This binding is a bit like setting up two $watch functions:

```
var parentGet = $parse(attrs['attribute2']);
var parentSet = parentGet.assign;
parentScope.$watch(parentGet, function(value) {
 isolatedScope.isolated2 = value;
});
isolatedScope.$watch('isolated2', function(value) {
 parentSet(parentScope, value);
});
```

The actual implementation is more complex to ensure stability between the two scopes.
Providing a callback expression in the
attribute with &
The & symbol indicates that the expression provided in the attribute on the element
will be made available on the scope as a function that, when called, will execute the
expression. This is useful for creating callbacks from the widget.
Building Your Own Directives
This binding is equivalent to $parse the expression in the attribute and exposing the
parsed expression function on the isolated scope:

```
parentGet = $parse(attrs['attribute3']);
scope.isolated3 = function(locals) {
    return parentGet(parentScope, locals);
};
```